# Publicar aplicações em stores que diferem por pequenos detalhes

Tags: android, ios, windows, appstore

Eu vejo alguma aplicações que são muito parecidas vou dizer até idênticas porem com uma marca diferente ou um detalhe pequeno.

Vou dar um exemplo: a Globosat tem apps de vários canais, mas é tudo o mesmo app com conteúdo diferente, pelo menos na maior parte.

Como isso funciona, cada um é diferente mesmo? Tem como reaproveitar? Seria possível publicar o mesmo app com marcas diferentes e que vai mudar o conteúdo de acordo com o que a marca instalada? Tem como ter uma espécie de DLL que pode ir em um app e aí outros que usam a mesma DLL não precisar mais dela?

Deu pra entender o que quero? Tem solução ou em celular é pior que em PC e desperdiça recursos mesmo?

Comment: A sua dúvida é se cada variante do aplicativo usa uma base de código separada (ex: são 3 ou 4 aplicativos diferentes) ou se todos usam um repositório central com branches específicas pra cada marca que são então distribuídas como aplicativos independentes? É isso?

Comment: Opa, não é a base de código, é o executável diferente também. A base aproveita muita coisa por isso eu queria criar essa espécie de DLL para não ter repetição no dispositivo, como a gente faz no desktop

Comment: De uma olhada sobre `flavors` https://medium.com/android-dev-br/flavors-2fa7b2ba4a9a

Comment: @LMaker tava lendo agora sobre o flavors, mas tenho uma situação que deve ser parecida com a do OP, são 3 apps quase iguais, mas para clientes diferentes, seria muito bom se tivesse como fazer alguma coisa parecida com uma lib compartilhada (em respeito ao espaço do aparelho dos usuários finais).

Comment: Acredito que a sugestão do *Android Flavors* sugerida pelo @LMaker é o que você está procurando. Inclusive não conhecia, achei bem interessante.

Comment: @Bacco Flavor atende ao problema, é assim que os APPs de banco funcionam, por exemplo.

Comment: @Bacco Se sua preocupação é com o tamanho do apk, não vejo problema. Pelo que eu entendo de Flavors, e posso até estar errado, mas quando tu faz o build, você faz para o `Flavor A`, o `Flavor B` não entra no pacote e não faz seu apk crescer com isso.

Comment: @lmaker obrigado ajudou, ainda verei se é a solução, você se importaria de responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `Product Flavor`.

Segundo a documentação:

> Product Flavors representam diferentes versões do seu app que você pode lançar para os usuários, como por exemplo versões gratuitas ou pagas do seu app. Você pode customizar seu product flavor para usar diferentes códigos e resources, enquanto compartilha e reusa as partes em comum com todas as versões do seu app.

Ou seja, `Product Flavors` servem para criar versões customizadas do mesmo aplicativo.

Para mais info, leia a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/)